# Porting LTT-ng modules on Android

Tags: android, porting, insmod, lttng

I was able to successfully port lttng modules for android. I could see required KO files being 
cross compiled for Panda board by using modinfo command .

However, When I try to insert one of the module "lttng-tracer.ko" using insmod, It throws the following error.

{{{

lttng_tracer: Unknown symbol tracepoint_probe_unregister (err 0)

}}}

Please help me in resolving this

Regards,

Sudharsanam..N

Answer (score 0):

It might be a module dependency problem. You need to install all the modules that *lttng-tracer* is dependent on before installing itself.

If it is the problem, you can check the folder where you put the modules (for example on Ubuntu it's */lib/modules/3.5.0.30-generic*). There you can find a file called *modules.dep*, which tells the sequence you should follow.